# how to handle Windows security dialog

Tags: internet-explorer-8, selenium-grid

Hi we have a authentication page that authenticates users. Recently our org performed some improvements to reduce the login prompts. Now when i use internet explorer i see a dialogbox to enter username/password. If i click ESC key then i can navigate to our authentication page. I am using remote web driver. I did try below things.
org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions actions = new org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions(context.getWebDriver());
actions.sendKeys(Keys.ESCAPE);

context.getWebDriver().switchTo().alert().dismiss()

None worked. "Windows Security" dialog box stays. Can anyone point me how to dismiss this dialog on internet explorer.
Thanks
Shankar KC

Comment: Hello there, i am blocked on IE testing. Can someone help me?

Comment: 5 days. No answers.....:(.....Hello can someone help me?

Comment: OK none replied. i found a workaround myself. This can be done using setting autologin. goto options -> security -> internet zone -> custom -> select "automatic login with current user name and password". This worked for me.